# Problemas para eliminar un registro

Tags: laravel

Tengo un sistema laravel que funciona, pero el único problema se me presenta al eliminar un registro, utilizo Laravel-Permission de la empresa Spatie, el problema está en que al hacer clic en el botón eliminar en vez de llevarme a la ru "delete" me lleva al "show" y en mis rutas tengo lo siguiente:

```
//PETS

    Route::get('pets', 'PetController@index')->name('pets.index')->middleware('permission:pets.index');

    Route::get('pets/create', 'PetController@create')->name('pets.create')->middleware('permission:pets.create');

    Route::post('pets/store', 'PetController@store')->name('pets.store')->middleware('permission:pets.store');

    Route::get('pets/{role}', 'PetController@show')->name('pets.show')->middleware('permission:pets.show');

    Route::get('pets/{role}/edit', 'PetController@edit')->name('pets.edit')->middleware('permission:pets.edit');

    Route::put('pets/{role}', 'PetController@update')->name('pets.update')->middleware('permission:pets.update');

    Route::delete('pets/{role}', 'PetController@destroy')->name('pets.destroy')->middleware('permission:pets.destroy');
```

Y en mi controlador:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $pet = Pet::find($id)->delete();

    return redirect()->route('pets.index')->with('info', 'Mascota eliminada con éxito.');
}
```

Botón:

```
<a href="{{ route('pets.destroy', $pet->id) }}" type="submit" class="button btn btn-sm btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
```

Comment: En el codigo que muestras no existe una peticion `delete`, busca como hacer una peticion `delete` en laravel y encontraras la solucion.

Comment: Gracias Shassain ya le agregué el form.